# Switching to the last application not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, alt-tab

In Windows 7 I can not switch to last app using a keyboard shortcut (possibly ALT+TAB).

**Current scenario:** I have 1 Word 2007 document opened. I start Total Commander and open another Word document with it - it opens in a new Word window. Now I want to switch back to Total Commander using a keyboard shortcut. I use ALT+TAB, but 1st Word document that was opened is brought to front instead of Total Commander.

**Desired scenario:** I have 1 Word 2007 document opened. I start Total Commander and open another Word document with it - it opens in a new Word window. I use a keyboard shortcut **(once only)** that brings me back to Total Commander.

Is there a way I can switch back to Total Commander using a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: What happens when you hit alt-tab twice?

Comment: Doing alt-tab twice works, but I want to only use it once. Seems my "bug" only is relevant to MS Office apps which have already some windows of themselves opened... but it just sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Alt+Tab then use directional keys(up, down, left, right) to navigate to the window you want

Comment: Not very efficient if its in the middle of a dozen or so applications.